# Value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'forEach'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am attempting to create a drop down menu within Xcode, but I am receiving the above error.

In the below code the object `dropDownOptions` is relating to the hidden buttons which are supposed to be unhidden when the button tied to `handleSelectionPressed` is pressed.

```
@IBOutlet weak var dropDownOptions: UIButton!

[...]

@IBAction func handleSelectionPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dropDownOptions.forEach { (button) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations:
                {button.ishidden = !button.ishidden})
        } 
    }
```

Couldn't find supporting docs online. Is there any fix or alternative solution.

Many thanks all.

Comment: `dropDownOptions` is a single button.  Did you perhaps mean to use a collection (array) of buttons.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's right. A silly mistake but it caught me. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `handleSelectionPressed` is a method that is run when clicking a button that reveals the `dropDownOptions`.

The thing that should be done is that instead of an `IBOutlet` the `UIButton` should be in a `IBOutletCollection`. Once you put them in a collection, your code should and will work.

When clicking and dragging from storyboard to your `UIViewController`, just select collection like in the image. And connect all your `UIButton` to this collection.

[image]